# Why javascript onclick event not working properly

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

Here is my code, when I run it with the help of onclick event, it doesn't work and prints blank pdf. But when I run this code directly with the help of **script** tag it works perfect, I want to run it with the help of button. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/iamgeekfool/8ztc5pnm/3/

```
var element = document.getElementById('exportPdf');
var opt = {
  margin:       1,
  filename:     'myfile.pdf',
  image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
   jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
   };

   // New Promise-based usage:
   html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();

   // Old monolithic-style usage:
   html2pdf(element, opt);
```

Comment: where is the onclick ?

Comment: Thanks, it's working when i shifted the onclick button to the top (below the body tag). But I want to put it below closing exportPdf, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Since the development team mentioned that there are some issues in latest version, we have to use v0.9.3

Refer: https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/

Updated Code: https://jsfiddle.net/t0L82nrp/1/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.3/html2pdf.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-YcsIPGdhPK4P/uRW6/sruonlYj+Q7UHWeKfTAkBW+g83NKM+jMJFJ4iAPfSnVp7BKD4dKMHmVSvICUbE/V1sSw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

```js
function exportPdf() {
    html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save(); 
}
```

Comment: Still not working, print blank pdf.

Comment: Can you again check it? in the JsFiddle link